# How to restrict orientation change which takes too long?

Tags: android

Hi dudes I developed one app to display friends on Map view working fine but while changing orientation re executing its taking time how overcome this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stop re-creation of Activity add

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

in your  tag in AndroidManifestFile.

Answer (score 0):

Prohibit orientation change or you can do you crucial initialization only once and save app state in bundle object.